# Read and use settings from appsettings.json in MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 project (framework 4.6.1), where I would like to load a POCO from appsettings.json.

My MVC app does not have a Startup.cs, starting point seems to be Global.asax.
I tried adding Owin to have a Startup.cs, but contrary to most articles I have found, Configuration seems to be a void method called during startup and not an IConfiguration as in net core.

[This article](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-5-configuration-and-ioptions) pretty much attempts to do what I want, but also assumes that Configuration is an IConfiguration interface.

Comment: The article you linked to is about ASP.NET Core MVC (previously referred to as MVC 6 and ASP.NET Core was previously called ASP.NET 5, but those names are defunkt now). However, do note you can make an ASP.NET Core application that targets .NET Framework.

Comment: Ok, that adds a  new level of confusion, however my app uses System.Web.Helpers.Chart, so ASP.NET Core is not an option for me, I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here is what I ended up doing:

I wanted to load an object of class `ScrumBan` from my appsettings.json.

I declared this class

```
public class ChartConfiguration: IChartConfiguration
{
    public Scrumban Scrumban { get; }
    public ChartConfiguration()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
        Scrumban = new Scrumban();
        configuration.GetSection("Scrumban").Bind(Scrumban);

    }
}
```

The interface only exposes the `ScrumBan` object:

```
public interface IChartConfiguration
{
    Scrumban Scrumban { get; }
}
```

Then i included Unity for Dependency Injection handling and registered my interface:

```
public static class IocExtensions
{
    public static void BindInRequestScope<T1, T2>(this IUnityContainer container) where T2 : T1
    {
        container.RegisterType<T1, T2>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    }

}

public class UnityMvc5
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // Configuration object, one per request, ensure it is disposed
        container.BindInRequestScope<IChartConfiguration, ChartConfiguration>();

        return container;
    }
}
```

Finally in Application_Start in Global.asax.cs I added the UnityMvc5.Start():

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityMvc5.Start();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

With Unity in place, I can now change my Controller constructors to include my IChartConfiguration interface and store it for future reference, exactly as is common practice with ASP.NET Core.

I am not quite sure about the instantiation model BindInRequestScope, I could have chosen the singleton, but as far as I can tell, the ChartConfiguration constructor is not called per request anyway. Similarly I am not sure of the value of reloadOnChange, but is not crucial to my app.

Hope this helps someone in a situation like mine.